# Convert datetimeString from file to datetime object

Tags: c++, datetime

i am reading date from file in C++ and the data contains `datetime string`. i have extracted `datetime string` from file but unable to convert it into `datetime object`.

The goal is to calculate time difference between two dates.

I have time in this format:
2021-03-01 09:00:00
in string:

Start: 2021-03-01 09:00:00, Stop: 2021-03-01 14:32:31

See if anybody can help

Here is my code ;

```
if (!MyReadFile) {
    cout << "file not found";
}

int counter = 0;
map<string, string> times;
while (!MyReadFile.eof()) {
    string line;
    getline(MyReadFile, line);
    
    string start_time = line.substr(6, 20);
    string end_time = line.substr(33, 51);
    
    time_t t;
    
    auto t_start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double elapsed_time_ms = chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end_time - start_time).count();
    
    times[start_time] = end_time;
    
    counter++;
}

for (auto& item : times) {
    cout << item.first << ":" << item.second << " " << endl;
}

cout << "Frequency is " << counter << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Update]

I've updated the original accepted answer:

1. Mainly to simplify the Pre C++20 code by using `get_time` and `difftime`.
2. To work in seconds, since the input values are in seconds.

---

- You don't need a `counter` if you want to count the file lines that contain different start/stop date pairs. You can just query `times` map's size at the end of your loop.
- You cannot either subtract strings, let alone expect that subtracting two strings containing text representing a date gives you the elapsed time between the two dates as output. (You can though use `operator+` to join two strings together.)

In short, what you can do is:

1. Read each file line, checking if it contains a start and a stop date. And if it does, parse the date and time fields out of each one.
2. Construct a date and time object out of those date and time fields, and use the start and stop objects to compute an elapsed time.

In the code below:

- I've assumed you may want to use a `std::map<std::pair<start_date_string, stop_date_string>, elapsed_time_ms>`, i.e., a map where the key is a pair of start date/stop date strings, and the value is an elapsed time in ms (double). That way, when you print the results, you can output both the date strings and the elapsed time.
- I only use a file line for testing purposes.
- Since input times are in seconds, I calculate time differences in seconds as well. [Updated]

---

### Pre C++20 [Updated]

- You can use `get_time` to directly parse the file line into a couple of `tm` structs.
- Then turn those `tm` structs to `time_t` structs, from which we can compute the elapsed time by using `difftime`.

https://godbolt.org/z/js3MY7Gnn

```
#include <ctime>  // tm, difftime
#include <iomanip>  // get_time
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <map>  // map
#include <utility>  // pair
#include <sstream>  // istringsteam
#include <string>  // string

int main()
{
    // File line
    const std::string line{"Start: 2021-03-01 09:00:00, Stop: 2021-03-01 14:32:31"};

    // Map of elapsed times for each start date/stop date pair of strings
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, double> times;

    // Check if file line matches our pattern
    std::istringstream iss{line};
    tm start_tm{};
    tm stop_tm{};
    if (iss >> std::get_time(&start_tm, "Start: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") and
        iss >> std::get_time(&stop_tm, ", Stop: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    {
        // Convert tm to time_t
        auto start_tt{mktime(&start_tm)};
        auto stop_tt{mktime(&stop_tm)};

        // Calculate elapsed time in s between the start and stop time_t
        double elapsed_time_s = std::difftime(stop_tt, start_tt);

        // Read start and stop dates into a pair of strings
        auto dt_strs{ std::make_pair(line.substr(7, 19), line.substr(34, 19)) };

        // Add results to the map
        times[dt_strs] = elapsed_time_s;
    }

    // Print the map
    for (const auto& [dt_strs, time] : times)
    {
        std::cout << dt_strs.first << ", " << dt_strs.second << " = " << time << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//     2021-03-01 09:00:00, 2021-03-01 14:32:31 = 19951
```

---

### C++20

The `std::chrono` library simplifies things even more. We can now parse the file line directly into a couple of time points, and compute the elapsed time from those time points. So we save a conversion between time structs.

```
#include <chrono>  // duration, from_stream, sys_time
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <map>  // map
#include <utility>  // pair
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>  // string

int main()
{
    // File line
    const std::string line{ "Start: 2021-03-01 09:00:00, Stop: 2021-03-01 14:32:31" };

    // Map of elapsed times for each start date/stop date pair of strings
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, double> times;

    // Read each date and time field into a couple of time points
    std::istringstream iss{ line };
    std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::seconds> start_tp{};
    std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::seconds> stop_tp{};
    if (std::chrono::from_stream(iss, "Start: %F %T", start_tp) and
        std::chrono::from_stream(iss, ", Stop: %F %T", stop_tp))
    {
        // Calculate elapse time in s between the start and stop time points
        double elapsed_time_s = std::chrono::duration<double>(stop_tp - start_tp).count();

        // Read start and stop dates into a pair of strings
        auto dt_strs{ std::make_pair(line.substr(7, 19), line.substr(34, 19)) };

        // Add results to the map
        times[dt_strs] = elapsed_time_s;
    }

    // Print the map
    for (const auto& [dt_strs, time] : times)
    {
        std::cout << dt_strs.first << ", " << dt_strs.second << " = " << time << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//     2021-03-01 09:00:00, 2021-03-01 14:32:31 = 19951
```

I have only been able to test this with VS2019. Compiler Explorer complained saying `from_stream` was no part of `std::chrono` when I tried compiling with x86-64 gcc (trunk) and x86-64 clang (trunk) [ *-std=c++20* ]; x64 msvc v.19latest [ */std:c++latest* ] compiles but doesn't execute the code.

Comment: Both `start_tm, stop_tm` deserve to have `stxxx_tm.tm_isdat = -1;`, else with `tm stxxx_tm{}; ... mktime(&stxxx_tm)` will assume time stamp are _standard time_.  Better to let `mktime()` deduce daylight time setting.  Try using a string that crosses a daylight savings time change to see the effect.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the comment! I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder how `chrono` handles parsing `%F %T` concenring DST.  I suspect it assumes the DST is to be deduced, akin to `.tm_isdst = -1;`.

Comment: It depends on the type being parsed, and on the information in the stream.  And it _never_ depends on the computer's local time zone.  If the type is a `time_point` based on `system_clock`, `%F %T` is always UTC because `sys_time` (`time_point`s based on `system_clock`) is defined as UTC.  If the type being parsed is `local_time`, then `%F %T` is parsed as _some_ local time which can be subsequently paired with _any_ `time_zone`.  If the format string and input parse an offset with `%z`, and if the type being parsed is `sys_time`, then the offset is applied to the parsed value to obtain UTC.

Comment: @HowardHinnant If I got you right, the following code would show the three cases you mentioned: https://godbolt.org/z/fPzsTKTxx